# Tab activities getting destroyed when switching

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs that I have created in this fasion

```
intent = new Intent(this, TestListActivity.class);
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
```

In one of them I have images loading from the web. but the problem is if I switch tabs and come back I'm loading the images all over again. Before my images stayed there once loaded but now every time I switch tabs the activity get destroyed. Any idea what I might have changed to cause this?

Comment: Have you used `setOffscreenPageLimit(int)` anywhere? The `int` param specified is how many unfocused tabs will be loaded at a given time (that is, if it's set to 0, you will always be reloading tabs).

Comment: No I haven't used that method anywhere. What object is that from? doesn't seem to be from TabHost.

Comment: Oh, I thought `TabHost` shared it with `ViewPager`. If you're using the same device as when it worked, I would check to make sure `setContent` is not called if the content is already initialized. Otherwise, I might consider switching to `ViewPager` (Android 4.0 standard, and supported in the v4 support library).